# Reindex catalogsearch_fulltext

Tags: magento2

Check my Magento 2 category pages, I get this error:

> We can't find products matching the selection.

So I ran the command

```
php bin/magento indexer:reindex catalogsearch_fulltext
```

But I got this error:

```
Catalog Search index process unknown error:
{"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"illegal_argument_exception","reason":"request [/magento2_product_1_v2/document/_mapping] contains unrecognized parameter: [include_type_name]"}],"type":"illegal_argument_exception","reason":"request [/magento2_product_1_v2/document/_mapping] contains unrecognized parameter: [include_type_name]"},"status":400}
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: With the version of ElasticSerch do you use?

Comment: In my Magento 2 Admin I'm seeing ElasticSearch 7. But according to Magneto 2 Requirement, it should be 7.6 for Magento 2.4.0. The problem is that when I tried to install ElasticSearch 7.6 with composer I got an error. Any suggestion for command to install ElasticSearch 7.6? Maybe that will resolve the problem.

Comment: Answer find again! I made some mistakes.

Answer (score 0):

There is issue in your elasticsearch, You need to execute below commands in command promopt,

```
curl -XPUT -H "Content-Type: application/json" http://localhost:9200/_cluster/settings -d '{ "transient": { "cluster.routing.allocation.disk.threshold_enabled": false } }'


curl -XPUT -H "Content-Type: application/json" http://localhost:9200/_all/_settings -d '{"index.blocks.read_only_allow_delete": null}'
```

After applied above commands do full text re-indexing,

Thanks & Regards,

Comment: Thanks for the support. I ran the commands you suggested, but I'm still getting the same error... Nothing changed.

Comment: Here's the screenshot in the Admin showing Elastic Search 7: https://prnt.sc/GMWwpjukAMLl

Comment: But according to Magento 2 requirements, Magento 2.4.0 is compatible with Elastic Search 7.6

Answer (score 0):

Found this [page](https://mirasvit.com/blog/magento-2-and-elasticsearch.html)  which indicated an out-of disk space problem (which is not the case, given 48GB free, here), but the command it mentioned, below, solved the problem.

```
curl -XPUT -H "Content-Type: application/json" http://localhost:9200/_all/_settings -d '{"index.blocks.read_only_allow_delete": null}'
```

Comment: Thanks for the support. But the above command didn't solve the issue... From what I'm seeing, Elastic Search is working properly, screenshot here: https://prnt.sc/_vRwd5yw1GIN So I doubt is the problem is related to elastic Search.